# Is a Zener and a fuse enough protection?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, protection, zener, fuses

We have a power chain that runs from an alternator, to a 24->12 dc regulator, to a battery charging circuit, to a 12 v battery.

We were thinking of using this circuit minus the ac-dc converter part for the charging circuit. http://www.circuitsgallery.com/2013/04/automatic-battery-charger-controller.html
And this regulator:
[http://www.amazon.com/HOSSEN%C2%AE-Converter-Regulator-Step-Down/dp/B00BWKXTUU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BWKXTUU)

From what I've heard, the battery should be charged at somewhere between 2 and 10 amps?

Is it enough protection for the battery/regulator to stick a 10 amp fuse and a 24v zener to ground between then alternator and the regulator? Also, do we need filtering circuitry or will the regulator take care of most of the noise?

Thank you!

Comment: Post *your* schematic please.

Comment: If you're trying to meet typical standards for automotive power systems fed by alternators, then your zener will be completely inadequate.  However, if you use a decent quality 24V to 12V convertor, it will take responsibility for this protection anyway.

Comment: When you use fuses and zeners, you should have an idea what you are trying to protect against. The most rigorous approach would be to pick a zener which can conduct, say, 2X the fuse current indefinitely. But that is a lot of power for a zener to dissipate. The idea is, in this case you can be sure that either the fuse will blow, or the zener will clamp the voltage to a safe level. Otherwise, there could be faults which fail out the zener, but do not blow the fuse.